# Why did C-3PO close down while Luke talked to Ben in A New Hope?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

When they were in Old Ben's dwelling, C-3PO made this strange request to Luke:

> THREEPIO: Sir, if you'll not be needing me, I'll close down for awhile.
>   LUKE: Sure, go ahead.

Why did he want to do that?

Comment: Have you never watched Futurama? The answer is "surfing for internet robo-porn".

Comment: He probably went into shock from all the excitement over the last two days.

Comment: I've always assumed that he was going to run some system diagnostic after being put together, and it required to turn off main functions.

Answer (score 25):

The [Star Wars in 100 Scenes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_in_100_Scenes) factbook confirms that his request to shut down was guided by it **aiding his mechanical systems in repairing his damaged arm.**

[image]

The official <s>Alan Dean Foster</s> George Lucas [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) of 'Star Wars: A New Hope' backs this up and gives us some additional dialogue that didn't appear in the film.

> “Sir?” came a familiar voice Luke hadn’t heard in a while.
>
> “What?” Luke was startled out of his examination.
>
> “If you’ll not be needing me,” Threepio declared, “I think I’ll shut
>   down for a bit. **It will help the armature nerves to knit, and I’m due
>   for some internal self-cleansing anyhow.”**

The [Star Wars NPR Radio Dramatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio)) (now non-canon but still good fun to listen to) contains a similar line:

> **Threepio:** *Sir, if you won't be needing me, I'll close down for a while **and run through some internal checks***

Comment: I bet it had to do with all that sand.

Comment: @cde -  I can't stand sand. It's coarse and rough and irritating, and it gets everywhere. A bit like Hayden Christensen.

Comment: This is the only one of the answers that is _supported by canon_. The rest are conjecture.

Comment: From some of the questions I've seen on this site, and all of them having an in-canon answer, they must hire legions of people just to take every line of dialog and write a book about it.

Comment: @Devsman - If you have a look at some of the EU novels, there are **entire book series'** based on background characters who appear for a few seconds.

Answer (score 13):

I've always seen it as a (rather transparent) way of taking Threepio 'off the stage' so to speak, so that the viewer can concentrate on the dialogue between Luke and Ben without distraction. This is clearly a major scene in the series, after all. So I doubt that there is a canon explanation because it's part of the filmmaking machinery.

Comment: It also meant they didn't have to worry about him moving around during the lightsaber effects shot.  C-3PO sitting there motionless would have been very strange if he hadn't shut down...

Comment: Being the only shiny thing in the room it would have been much harder to have to keep re-estimating the position of the reflection, so being still would have made it much easier to draw. Erm, not that the lightsabers weren't real...

Answer (score 12):

> Threepio shook his head slowly. "Quite frankly, sir, I don't know what he is talking about. Our last master was Captain Colton. I've never heard Artoo mention a prior master. I've certainly never heard of an Obi-Wan Kenobi. But with all we've been through", he concluded apologetically, "I'm afraid his logic circuits have gotten a bit scrambled. He's become decidedly eccentric at times." And while Luke considered this turn of events, **Threepio took the opportunity to throw Artoo a furious look of warning.** (src: "Star Wars: ANH  novelization", after Luke first sees Leia's hologram).

This last statement is very out of place, unless C-3PO did not want Luke to know the full story (possibly on orders from Bail Organa) yet.

So, knowing that he's a complete and utter blabbermouth otherwise, he shut down so as to not spill any secrets while Ben Kenobi talked about Anakin Skywalker.

There's no canon support for this, but it's one of the few explanations that makes sense, since we don't see any 0BBY era droids needing to shut down for some strange reason otherwise.

Comment: The theory's not mine. Source: http://www.sirstevesguide.com/showthread.php/9101-R2D2-and-C3PO-get-their-memories-wiped/page2

Comment: This theory date from 2002, before we even know that C-3PO had his memory wiped, as it was stated in Revenge of the Sith. Remark that the first post on the link you provided was amazingly prescient, correctly guessing that C-3PO had his memory wiped 3 year before it was known. Anyway, that cannot be the reason C-3P0 shut down, he cannot tell the truth to Luke about Anakin: he don't remember.

Comment: @DavRob60 - memory wipe == doesn't remember. Memory wipe != doesn't know from fresher sources.

Comment: Yeah, right, I wipe my Droid's memory so I could explain him back the very things I wanted him to forget. C-3P0 had this memory wipe so it fit the fact he don't remember anything in the original trilogy, and in the extended universe. He is not supposed the remember. The *furious look of warning* was just because R2 didn't comply to Luke's orders, which annoyed C-3P0.

Comment: Strange that the novelization says "Our last master was Captain Colton." when in the film he quite clearly says "Captain Antilles"...

Comment: @NorbyTheGeek - novelizations are often written from early script drafts. Sometimes, it's an improvement (see The Force Awakens one)

Answer (score -1):

I too am puzzled as to why 3PO feels the need to close down during the scene with Luke and Ben, the only reason I can see is it has something to do with the light saber being used in the shot, which passes in front of 3PO, it may have been easier for the FX guys if 3PO was stationary at the time of the effects being used, so not having reflections etc to deal with. Just a theory not sure if this is right. Craig.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a new user I would recommend a couple things to you. Check out what others post both questions and answer to kind of learn the format that's used. What you did here with this answer is more of a comment then an answer. You can click on the "add comment" button under any post and comment or ask the original poster or answerer a question. We generally don't put a "me too" at the beginning of an answer. An answer should be authortative, insightful, and include canon (in-universe) material. Quotes from the movie, authors notes, etc. are most helpful. -cont'd-

Comment: If you remove the "me too" part of your answer, add something from the production notes or something else that quotes somebody making your claims, I think this could be a really strong answer. You might even get awarded a correct answer on your first try which is rare. Please edit this question to add these elements or change this to a comment. Welcome again and enjoy the site.